# create plsql trigger for any DML operations performed in any tables

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger, audit-trail

I have around 500 tables in DB. If there is any DML operations performed on that table then trigger should be fired to capture those dml activities and should load it into an audit table. I dont want to write 500 individual triggers. Any simple method to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want to audit? How granular do you need the information?

Answer (score 2):

To switch all high level auditing of DML statements for all tables:

```
 AUDIT INSERT TABLE, UPDATE TABLE, DELETE TABLE;
```

What objects we can manage depends on what privileges we have. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_4007.htm#i2059073).

AUDIT will write basic information to the audit trail. The destination depends on the value of [the AUDIT_TRAIL parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/initparams017.htm#REFRN10006). If the parameter is set to `db` the output is written to a database table: we can see our trail in USER_AUDIT_TRAIL or (if we have the privilege) everything in [DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/statviews_3081.htm#REFRN23023).

The audit trail is high level, which means it records that user `FOX` updated the `EMP` table but doesn't tell us which records or what the actual changes were. We can implement granular auditing by creating Fine-Grained Audit policies. This requires a lot more work on our part so we may decide not to enable it for all our tables. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/auditing.htm#DBSEG525).

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are used on tables only, not the entire database.  Ignoring the complexity of maintaining disparate data types, data use, context of various tables and their use, what you are looking for would be extremely complex, something no RDBMS has addressed at the database level.

There is some information on triggers at this link:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch15.htm

You could place a trigger on each table that calls the same procedure ... but then all that complexity comes into play.

Comment: "Triggers are used on tables only, not the entire database." Up to a point. We can define system level triggers to fire on various database events.